# Firebase JavaScript retrieve dynamically created child key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Experimenting with Firebase and am trying to get the newly added child that is being added dynamically. How can I retrieve just: pi0usqkj16o ?

```
var availability = database.ref("games/setup");
availability.once("value", function(snapshot){

    console.log(JSON.stringify( snapshot.val() ) );

});
```

`snapshot.val()` gives me the following:

```
{
    "pi0usqkj16o":{
        "player1":"ed",
        "player1Choice":"",
        "player1Wins":0,
        "player2":"",
        "player2Choice":"",
        "player2Wins":0,
        "total":0
    },
    "wpgnfq1swac":{
        "player1":"ed",
        "player1Choice":"",
        "player1Wins":0,
        "player2":"",
        "player2Choice":"",
        "player2Wins":0,
        "total":0
    }
}
```

The end goal would be to target the newly created directory (child) that is dynamically created and given a serial number name. perhaps doing something like this?
 var name = pi0usqkj16o; database.ref("somefolder/" + name); `

but how would i be able to isolate just the serial from the above json returned?

```
//App Code

  //INITIALIZE FIREBASE
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var database = firebase.database();


  var Methods = {

  //Makes a new serial (ex. pi0usqkj16o)
  function uniqueId(){
              return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16);
            }

  //checks if a game room is already available
  initialCheck: function(callback){
        var availability = database.ref("games/setup");
        availability.once("value", function(snapshot){

          //if there is no readily available room already created..create a new room 
          if(snapshot.numChildren() < 1){
            var gameName = uniqueId();

            availability.update({
              [gameName]: {player1: "ed", player2: "", player1Choice: "", player2Choice: "", player1Wins: 0, player2Wins: 0, total: 0}
            });
          }
          else{
            var room = snapshot.key;
            // Need to find the room name to be able to assign it to the user.
            console.log("room is: " + room );
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: You can't make shallow queries with the Realtime Database. `once` always pulls all the data under the key. You can call `snapshot.key` in the closure to get the value of the key, but keep in mind the function `once` still downloads all the data.

Comment: Are you trying to only get the recently added child, and not the other one? How was this child added?

Comment: If you want to listen for a child added, use the `on` 'child_added' event. Otherwise, I suggest using `push()` to let Firebase index your data for you in chronological order. Then you can query using `LimitToLast(1)` to get the most recent

Comment: the serial number is a newly created directory (child). if i want to target a specific directory i would make a reference ` database.ref("somefolder/hello"); ` but in this case the directory is being created dynamically so i am not sure how to call the reference so i am trying to get the name so that i can do something like this   ` var name = pi0usqkj16o;   database.ref("somefolder/" + name); `

Comment: Where does your unique id `pi0usqkj16o` come from? How is it generated? I know you are just experimenting, but it looks like your structure is for some simple 2 player game. You must know the ID of the players? Then save the player id in the database with a reference to the game id. Then you are able to pull down only the game you want.

Comment: You are correct  :-) i am trying to learn to make a 2 player game. player 1 goes, there is no room so a room is created dynamically with a room name of serial number generated. The player than waits for player 2. Player 2 checks if a room is available, in this case a room is available it will be pi0usqkj16o for this example. so player 2 is assigned to this room in firebase and locally to be able to retrieve only that game room. i am a newbee perhaps i am approaching this wrong? i want to dynamically create a room so that if there are more than 2 players than those go to a newly created room.

Comment: i've added the full code was added to the original post

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that EXACT key, there would have to be some unique data in there that you can easily reference. Here's an idea:

```
{
"pi0usqkj16o":{
    "player1":"ed",
    "player1Choice":"",
    "player1Wins":0,
    "player2":"",
    "player2Choice":"",
    "player2Wins":0,
    "total":0,
    "gameNumber":1
},
"wpgnfq1swac":{
    "player1":"ed",
    "player1Choice":"",
    "player1Wins":0,
    "player2":"",
    "player2Choice":"",
    "player2Wins":0,
    "total":0,
    "gameNumber":2
 }
}
```

I've added a 'gameNumber' to your data that should be unqiue after each game. Now to get the exact key:

```
firebase.database().ref('games/setup').once("value", function(snapshot){
   var data = snapshot.val();
   if (data && snapshot.child('gameNumber').val() === '1'){
     console.log(snapshot.key);
   } else {
     console.log("no data"); 
   }
});
```

This should return the key you are looking for. Of course you would need to sit back and think about a way to re-structure your data in order to make queries like this.

Give this a read as well:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot